# Any update on OAuth support for databricks and Rstudio via databricks connect v2?

Tags: rstudio, databricks, databricks-connect

Wondering if there is any workaround for connecting Rstudio desktop to databricks outside of the personal access token?  At positconf(2023) they mentioned oauth was coming. My org does not allow personal access tokens. Wondering if anyone had more insight on how else to connect Rstudio desktop to databricks or if there was an update to scheduled release of oauth support for databricks connect.